# YouTube keeps redirecting me to a strange address: “youtube.xcdn.app”

Tags: networking, dns, youtube, isp

Every time I try to connect to YouTube  with any browser it redirects me to this strange address:

```
youtube.xcdn.app
```

Ii tried to check if this address is available to everyone via “[Is It Up or Down?](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/youtube.xcdn.app.html)” or it is just me and as expected it is only for me:

[[image: Screenshot]]

I tried changing my DNS and still get the same result.

So what could be the problem? It is something todo with my ISP? and if so, why would they do something like that?

Comment: Where in the world are you located? This could be an ISP related block based on geolocation.

Comment: I Guess so, the problem started after i changed the isp, but the main point is, why are they doing this?

Comment: So again… “Where in the world are you located?” What country are you in?

Comment: Yeah, im located in Lebanon

Comment: Consider using Firefox and enabling DNS over HTTPS (DoH). It's designed to make it so your DNS can't be snooped on or spoofed by a bad ISP or government.

Comment: If it's not caused by a crappy ISP or untrustworthy political regime, it could be caused by a compromised modem, router, or client device. That is, your modem, router, or Linux PC may have been infected by malware or hacked.

Comment: @Spiff well,  i already check for malware and everything, im sure the problem is from the isp itself, the problem appeared when i change it, i will try to use DoH and see the results

Comment: @Spiff Thank you so much, i used DoH with Firefox and the issue was solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was From the ISP. I am still not sure why they are doing this. I will try to contact them later on. I was able to solve this issue as [@Spiff mentioned in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1540578/youtube-keeps-redirecting-me-to-a-strange-address-youtube-xcdn-app?noredirect=1#comment2340017_1540578) by using DNS over HTTPS (DoH)

I have set `network.trr.mode` value in Firefox to 3 so it use DoH only and disables regular DNS.